# What is the name of this fragrant flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, perennials, outdoor

Can anyone identify this flower?
It started its flower about a week ago and has an amazing frangrance.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the plant is no more than 12 inches/30cm tall (and most likely shorter than that), then this is a common garden hyacinth, but one that's been in the ground awhile and has lost its compact growth habit. A photo from farther away would be helpful in this ID.

I first thought we were looking at English or Spanish Bluebells (*Hyacinthoides* species), but the ovaries (if that's the correct bit I'm talking about) on those flowers are not noticeable, whereas they are noticeable on hyacinths.